# asp.net Service responds with 500 in integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have a website who has an webservice in it. It looks like this:

```
<ScriptService> _
<WebService(Namespace := "http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo := WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<DesignerGenerated>
Public Class FooWebService
    Inherits WebService

    <WebMethod>
    Public Shared Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

In the root directory is a file FooWebService.asmx

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/Src/FooWebService.vb" Class="FooWebService" %>
```

And I register it this way in my .ascx:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/FooWebService.asmx"/>
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

This works so far as long as I am running the website in classic mode. As soon as I switch to integrated this won't work any longer. I get this message back on load on the js console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

on the path:  http://localhost:3874/FooWebService.asmx/jsdebug  (localy debugged)

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Is there a more detailed message in the Windows event logs?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using asmx web services in new code.  Microsoft [acknowledged](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%e2%80%9clegacy-technology%e2%80%9d/) seven years ago that asmx web services is a legacy product.

Comment: unfortunately there are no furhter infos in the event log..
@ClintB it's legacy code. I just try to make it work with the integrated mode. But what is the new way to do it anyway? Maybe I rewrite.